# How to create my own .pbf route to make a graph in open trip planner

Tags: r, gis, openstreetmap, r-sf, osm.pbf

I was trying to generate isochrones in specific routes, for this purpose I am using Open Trip Planner following the Marcus Young ([Tutorial #1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/opentripplanner/vignettes/opentripplanner.html) [Tutorial #2](https://github.com/marcusyoung/otp-tutorial)). At this moment I am in the GRAPH folder step trying to put the necessary files, I have the GTFS data and but I need the required OSM road map in .pbf format, I am trying to create my own OSM road map from my own bus stop and routes that I can have in various format (as a simple geometry in shapefile format or as a geometry collection as geojson or geopackage format).

My first try was to export a geometry collection from the R library in .pbf format, but the OSM file doesn't permit write files.

Now I was about to start to edit from [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) software, but if someone can tell me **How can I generate my own OSM road map in .pbf format from my own files (mentioned above)**, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You can dowload OSM data from [geofabrik](http://www.geofabrik.de/)

See more details for using OTP and R at https://docs.ropensci.org/opentripplanner/index.html